# How create trial version without webserver

Tags: android, trial

I write an android app and i want make 30 days trial version to test next if user like to continue with app he had to buy ( inApp purchase ) .
how can i make this feature without webserver

Answer (score 0):

You can make one app for both (trial and complete) and use the Market/Play API to see if the user has paid for the product (using in app billing) and try to use a resource/file/database (I guess the file is the better option, but need to test the uninstall behave) to flag when the user has started using the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file on SD card that should be updated accordingly when app is opened. You can do so using shared preferences also but re-installing app will reset your counter of days or what ever logic you will use. you can hide file and use some encryption to make it less susceptible to hack.